# Why does PuTTY stop working when it's moved to another directory?

Tags: windows-xp, putty

I encountered a weird issue with PuTTY on Windows XP:

1. I downloaded PuTTY.exe (client) and placed it on my desktop. After configuring it, I successfully connected to the server on port 22.
2. I then closed PuTTY and moved the PuTTY.exe to a new file directory (any other directory); nothing else was changed. The connection now can't be established, PuTTY reports:

   > "Network error: connection refused"
3. When I move PuTTY.exe back to the desktop, it works again.
4. If I try the same thing on my friend's PC, PuTTY.exe works in all directories; I can place it anywhere and it works.

Why does PuTTY.exe only work in a particular directory on my PC?

---

Yes PuTTY should work in any directory. I also feel very weired when this happens to me. Somehow I need PuTTY.exe to work in another file directory, so pls help.

I have tried:

1. uninstall all firewalls/anti-virus in my PC except Windows XP firewall(non-uninstallable)
2. turn off Windows firewall

but no luck.. I also tried add exceptions of PuTTY.exe(new directory), port22(TCP) and port22(UDP) to the Windows firewall, still doesn't work...

Any other way I can change firewall settings? Or any other way I can debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it on your desktop?

Try adding an exception for it in your firewall; it happened to me and that fixed it.

Comment: I agree it sounds like a workstation firewall issue.  Putty is standalone, and can be placed in any directory without issue.